# Vectorization using `np.vectorize`

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to vectorize the following function using `np.vectroize`:

```
def f(x):
if 0<=x<=1:
    return 0.5
elif 1<x<=3:
    return 0.25
else:
    return 0
```

Next step:

```
f = np.vectorize(f)
```

However, if I put negative values in the input array for `f`, all of a sudden all the output values become zero. There is no problem when all values are positive. For example:

```
f([-0.1,1,2,3,4])
```

output is:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: "all of a sudden all the output values become zero" because negative numbers does not fall into the first condition `if 0<=x<=1:` nor the second `elif 1<x<=3:`, so zero is returned from `else` branch

Comment: @ Jan That can be correct for the first element. Not for other five elements.

Comment: Read all of its docs, including the bit about `otypes` and the speed disclaimer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is type of your array. According to [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

> The data type of the output of vectorized is determined by calling the function with the first element of the input.

the type is determined by the first value, which is `0`, therefore the type is integer. If you return `0.25` or `0.5`, it is converted to `0` (as `int(0.25)` and `int(0.5)` is `0`)

Solution:

```py
f = np.vectorize(f,"d")
```

or

```py
return 0.0 # or float(0), but must be float
```